# How can I add javascript object to another object in dynamic

Tags: javascript, object, addition

Suppose I have several javascript object

```
{"type":"gotopage","target":"undefined"}
{"type":"press","target":"a"}
{"type":"rotate","target":"long"}
```

How can I add this objects to another object like

```
config={}
```

I know how to if each inserted object have a id I can added as:

```
config["id"]={}
```

But in this case how can I add objects without id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are mixing up objects and arrays. Objects have named keys, arrays have numeric keys. You can easily append to an array using `.push()`:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("something");
```

However, for a configuration object as your variable name suggests this is not really useful. You should rather use meaningful names for your options, e.g.:

```
var config = {
    something: 'blah',
    foo: 'bar'
};
```

You can also store an array in your object:

```
config.manyStuff = [];
for(...) {
    manyStuff.push(...);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
var obj1 = {"type":"gotopage","target":"undefined"};

var config = {};
config.obj1 = obj1;
```

You can always add them later.

```
var obj1 = {"type":"gotopage","target":"undefined"};

var config = {};
config.obj1 = obj1;

var obj2 = {"key":"data"};
config.obj2 = obj2;
```

Comment: but I don't konw how many obj I have,I can not define them previously

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add object you can easily add using use spread operator.

Example ->

```
object1 = { property1: 1, property2: 2}
finalObject = [{...object1}]
```

**finalObject = {...object1}**

and as per your question solution use array object here

**finalObject = [{...object1}]**

```js
object1 = { property1: 1, property2: 2}
    finalObject = [{...object1}]
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(finalObject);
```

```html
<div id = "demo"></div>
```

Comment: Actually this will reset the `finalObject` and not add to it as the original question asked.

Answer (score 2):

If these data you have are of the same type, then use an array instead:

```
var some_data = {"type":"gotopage","target":"undefined"}

var config = [];
var config.push(some_data); //and do this for the rest
```

And you can access the config items like this:

```
var someVariable = config[index]; //where index is a number starting from 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this utility function:

```
module.exports.combine = function() {

  var rv = {};
  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    for (thing in arguments[i]) {
        rv[thing]=arguments[i][thing];
    }
  }
  return rv;
}
```

Properties with the same name will be overwritten by properties in later arguments

```
var util = require('lib/util.js');
console.log(util.combine(
  {"1":"one","two":function(){;},
  {"four":{"four.5":"four.5-b"}, "5":"foo"}});
```

result:

```
    { '1': 'one',
    '5': 'foo',
    two: [Function],
    four: { 'four.5': 'four.5-b' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add/append one object content to another such as,

```js
let obj = { id:"hello", class: "world"};
let extra = {style:"{color:red}"};

obj = {...obj, ...extra}; //extra values will be appended to obj.
```

However, note that if you original object is declared as a `const` then it cannot be reassigned, and therefore the following solution will work,

```js
const obj = {id:"hello", class: "world"};
let extra = {style:"{color:red}"};

Object.keys(extra).forEach(k=> obj[k] = extra[k]);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking to add them during intialization, this might help you out:

```
 var config = [
               {"type":"gotopage","target":"undefined"},
               {"type":"press","target":"a"},
               {"type":"rotate","target":"long"}
              ]
```